# Get text string between first and 2nd comma

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Let's say I have this text within a specific H1 called ".prop-address h1":

```
<h1>31620 NE 129th St, Duvall, WA 98019</h1>
```

How do I get the text "Duvall" (text between first & second comma) with Jquery/JS so I can use it for whatever purposes? I've looked up a bunch of stuff but can't seem to make it work. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried ?

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $('#result').text($('#test').text().split(',')[1])
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1 id='test'>31620 NE 129th St, Duvall, WA 98019</h1>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<h1 class='prop-address'>31620 NE 129th St, Duvall, WA 98019</h1>
<script>
  var text = document.querySelector("h1.prop-address").firstChild.nodeValue;
  var res = text.split(',')[1].trim();
  console.log(res)
</script>
```